# Write triangle angle bisector as a linear combination of side vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $AO$ be the bisector of $\angle A$ in a triangle $ABC$. How to write the vector $\overrightarrow{AO}$ as a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $O$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The center $I$ of the inscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$ 
is expressed as a linear combination of the vertices as 
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}
where

\begin{align} 
a&=\|\overrightarrow{BC}\|=\|\overrightarrow{AC}-\overrightarrow{AB}\|
,\\
b&=\|\overrightarrow{AC}\|,\ c=\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|
,
\end{align}

So, if we move the origin to the point $A$,
then from \eqref{1} the bisector of $\angle A$ is

\begin{align} 
\overrightarrow{AI}
&=
\frac{
\|\overrightarrow{AC}\|\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}
+\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}
}{
\|\overrightarrow{AC}-\overrightarrow{AB}\|
+\|\overrightarrow{AC}\|+\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|
}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

As @John Hughes pointed out, 
since $\overrightarrow{AO}$
is expected to be just the direction vector,
the expression \eqref{2}
can be simplified:

\begin{align} 
\overrightarrow{AO}
&=
\|\overrightarrow{AC}\|\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}
+\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Or, since OP apparently only needs the direction vector of the bisector you can leave off the denominator entirely and simplify things a bit.

Comment: @John Hughes: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You might want to let 
$$
v = \frac{1}{\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|} \overrightarrow{AB}
$$
and work from there.